# Delete row in mysql via form input by id

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I am attempting to remove mysql row data via input from a form. I can not get the data to delete from my table or throw any errors. I simply would like to type in my form in the id I would like to remove from my database.

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","######");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("test", $con);
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Blog` WHERE `Id` = '$id'")  or die (mysql_error());

$id = $_GET['Id'] ;
?>

<form action="#" method="get">
 Delete: <input type="text" name="Id"><br>  
         <input type="submit" value="delete">
</form>
```

Comment: You are assigning `$id` _after_ you use it.

Comment: You must first [read over this question thoroughly though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, and indeed it is trivially easy for anyone to delete everything in your table.  Turn up error_reporting and show errors on screen (always while developing code) and you'll see notices about undefined variables. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Ok thanks Michael. I moved the $id up about the query and it works now. I have tried attaching the error_reporting that you gave me but it breaks every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this call the `$id` first and `delete query` next.

```
 <?php 
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","######");
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("test", $con);

    $id = $_GET['Id'] ;
    $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Blog` WHERE `Id` = '$id'")  or die (mysql_error());


    ?>

<form action="#" method="get">
 Delete: <input type="text" name="Id"><br>  
         <input type="submit" value="delete">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this define `$id` before query and
if your id field in your database type intager try this `{$id}`

```
$id = $_GET['Id'] ;
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Blog` WHERE `Id` = {$id}")  or die (mysql_error());
```